# Error in the @GeneratedValue JPA Tag

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am Creating a class in a project using JPA,and i want to map  the class into a database using JPA TAGs, but i am getting an error, in this part:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "SIGAC_TIPUS_VALORACIO")
public class SigacTipusValoracio implements Serializable, DibaEntity, DibaSelectItem {


    /**
     *  The Constant serialVersionUID.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6560479364918284265L;

    /**
     * The tva id tipus valoracio.
     */
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name= "SIGAC_TIPUS_VALORACIO_TVAIDTIPUSVALORACIO_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SIGAC_SEQ_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SIGAC_TIPUS_VALORACIO_TVAIDTIPUS_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "TVA_ID_TIPUS", precision= 12)
    private Long tvaIdTipusValoracio;
```

exactly in generator attribute of the @GeneratedValue tag.
does anyone know why  ?

Comment: Can you write what error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   @SequenceGenerator(name= "SIGAC_TIPUS_VALORACIO_TVAIDTIPUSVALORACIO_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SIGAC_SEQ_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SIGAC_TIPUS_VALORACIO_TVAIDTIPUS_GENERATOR")
```

The `Name` attribute of `SequenceGenerator` is
 "**SIGAC_TIPUS_VALORACIO_TVAIDTIPUSVALORACIO_GENERATOR**".

The `generator` attribute of `GeneratedValue` is 
"**SIGAC_TIPUS_VALORACIO_TVAIDTIPUS_GENERATOR**".

It isn't a same ids. I recommend not use such big Ids.